# Remove specific value from array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got an array with different school grades. This data is gathered from a json file. In this array there are also grades that are 0. These are grades from students that didn't complete the course. I want to remove all the 0 in the array, but I have no idea how to start.

example of the array:

```
var grades = [7,6,4,0,4,8,9,6,6,10,0,7,8,6,7]
```

p.s. I'm using d3

Comment: Have you tried [searching on google](https://www.google.com/search?oq=remove+zeros+from+array+javascript)?

Comment: Ofcourse but i couldn't find anything. Also I'm new to d3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var nonzero = grades.filter(function(v) {
    return v !== 0;
});
```

As commenteers correctly noted, `.filter` is not avail in all browsers. You can use the shim available on MDN (see link above), or re-write your code to something like this:

```
var i=0, len = grades.length, nonzero = [];
for(;i<len;i++) {
    grades[i] !== 0 && nonzero.push(grades[i]);
}
```

Comment: It should be warned that this is part of javascript 1.6 and may not be 100% supported.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant piece of code but it works.

```
  var grades = [7,6,4,0,4,8,9,6,6,10,0,7,8,6,7],
      newGrades = [],
      grade;

  while (grades.length) {
    grade = grades.pop();

    if (grade != 0)
        newGrades.push(grade);
  }

  grades = newGrades;
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive but still works:

```
    var grades = [7,6,4,0,4,8,9,6,6,10,0,7,8,6,7];
    var j=0;
    var newgrades=[];
    for (var i=0; i < grades.length; i++) {
      if (grades[i]) {
        newgrades[j++] = grades[i]; 
        } 
    }
```

grades = newgrades;

Answer (score 0):

Try `.splice()` method

```
var grades = [7, 6, 4, 0, 4, 8, 9, 6, 6, 10, 0, 7, 8, 6, 7];

while (true) {
    var index = grades.indexOf(0);
    console.log(index);
    if (index > 0) {
        grades.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(grades);
​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wdy5P/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<=grades.length; i++){
    if(grades[i]==0){
        grades.splice(i,1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t forget to `===`-check zero, or any falsy value will be removed.

Comment: Since this is a set of numbers, perhaps removing falsy values should be intended. Either way, I don't advocate excessive use of `===`, and it is not necessary given the parameters of the question.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. "remove all the 0 in the array" is pretty clear to me though... In your case you could just do `!grades[i]`

Comment: Fair enough, but with no performance benefit of one over the other, it's probably better to write it the way I did, because it implies the intent (to check if the value of `grades[i]` is zero).